# Explain the result of Pohlig-Hellman algorithm.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-logarithms

At this discrete-logarithm calculator: https://www.alpertron.com.ar/DILOG.HTM. Let base = 2, pow = 2 and modulus = 1009 * 3643 = 3675787. (Note both 1009 and 3643 are prime numbers.). The solution obtained is:

Find exp such that $2^{exp}$ ≡ 2 (mod 3675787)

exp = 1 + 305928k

The calculator is using the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm. I cannot figure out how the 305928 term shows up in the result.

I followed all the steps shown in this answer: [Use Pohlig-Hellman to solve discrete log](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074377/use-pohlig-hellman-to-solve-discrete-log). We get the result x = 1, but not the 305928k term.

Can someone explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of 2 modulo $n=3675787$ is
$$\mathrm{ord}_{3675787}(2) = 305928$$
i.e. $305928\;$ is the smallest positive exponent $x$ with $2^x=1 \pmod n$