# Solving DLP using the method of Pohlig-Hellman

Tags: cryptography, chinese-remainder-theorem, discrete-logarithms

I want to solve the DLP for $p=29$, $a=2$ and $b=5$ using the method of Pohlig-Hellman.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We have that $p-1=28=2^2\cdot 7$.

We get \begin{align*}&x_2= x\pmod {2^2} \\ &x_7=x\pmod 7\end{align*}

$x_2$ is a number $\mod 4$, so $x_2=c_0+c_1(2)$ with coefficients $0$ or $1$.

We have that \begin{equation*}b^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=5^{14}\equiv 1\end{equation*}

Since this is equal to $a^{c_0\cdot \frac{p-1}{2}}$ we have that $c_0=0$.

We divide $b$ by $a^{c_0}=1$ and we get $b\cdot a^{-c_0}=b=5$.

We have that $5^{\frac{p-1}{4}}=5^7\equiv 28$.

Since this is equal to $a^{c_1\cdot \frac{p-1}{2}}$ we have that $c_1=1$.

Therefore, $x_2=c_0+c_1(2)=1$.

$x_7$ is a number $\pmod 7$.

So, $x_7=c_0$ with $c_0\in \{0,\ldots , 6\}$.

We have that $b^{\frac{p-1}{7}}=5^4\equiv 16$.

This this is equal to $a^{c_0\cdot \frac{p-1}{7}}=2^{4c_0}$ we have that $c_0=1$.

So $x_7=c_0(7)=1$.

We use the Chinese theorem for the system \begin{align*}x=1\pmod 4 \\ x=1\pmod 7\end{align*} 
Solving this one we get that $x\equiv 1$.

Is everything correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a guide, we will use the MSE post - [Pohlig-Hellman Algorithm for solving a DLP - can $x_0$ have > 1 solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514365/pohlig-hellman-algorithm-for-solving-a-dlp-can-x-0-have-1-solution/2514422).

A description of the algorithm can be found in

- $(1)$ A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography, 2nd Ed., N. Koblitz
- $(2)$ An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography, J. Hoffstein, J.
  Pipher, J. H. Silverman
- $(3)$ Number Theory for Computing, 2nd Ed., S. Y. Yan
- $(4)$ An Introduction to Cryptography, R. A. Mollin

We will use the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm to solve a [*Discrete
Log Problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) to
find $x$ in

$$2^x = 5 \pmod{101}$$

Using the notation from $(2)$

$$g^x = h \pmod p$$

We have

$$g = 2, h = 5, p = 101, N = p - 1 = 100 = \prod_{i=1}^{n} q_i^{e_i} = q_1^{e_1}
\cdot q_2^{e_2} = 2^2 \cdot 5^2 $$

We can summarize the necessary algorithm calculations in a handy table as

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  \large q  & \large e & \large g^{(p-1)/q^e} & \large h^{(p-1)/q^e} &
\mbox{Solve}~ \large \left(g^{(p-1)/q^e} \right)^x = ~ \large
h^{(p-1)/q^e}~ \mbox{for} ~ \large x \\  \hline
2 & 2 & 10 & 1 & \mbox{Calculation I = ?}\\
   \hline
5 & 2 & 16 & 19 & \mbox{Calculation II = ?}\\  \hline
\end{array}$$

**Calculation I:** Solve

$$x \equiv x_0 + x_1q + \ldots + x_{e-1}q^{e−1} \pmod {2^2} \equiv
x_0 + 2x_1 \pmod {2^2}$$

- Solve $(10)^x = 1 \pmod {101}$ for $x_0, x_1$.
- $x_0: (10^{2^1})^{x_0} = 100^{x_0} = 1^{2^1} \pmod {101} \implies (100)^{x_0}
  = 1 \pmod{101} \implies x_0 = 2$
- $x_1: (10^{2^1})^{x_1} = 100^{x_1} = (1 \times 10^{-x_0})^{2^0} \pmod {101} \implies (100)^{x_1} = 100 \pmod{101} \implies x_1 = 1$

Our first result is

$$x \equiv x_0 + 2 x_1 \pmod {2^2} \equiv 2 + 2
\pmod {2^2} \equiv 0 \pmod {2^2}$$

**Calculation II:** Solve

$$x \equiv x_0 + x_1q + \ldots + x_{e-1}q^{e−1} \pmod {5^2} \equiv
x_0 + 5 x_1 \pmod {5^2}$$

- Solve $(16)^x = 19 \pmod {101}$ for $x_0, x_1$.
- $x_0: (16^{5^1})^{x_0} = 95^{x_0} = 19^{5^1} \pmod {101} = 84 \pmod{101} \implies x_0 = 4$.
- $x_1: (16^{5^1})^{x_1} = 95^{x_1} = (19 \times 16^{-x_0})\pmod{101} = (19 \times 16^{-4})\pmod{101} = (19 \times 31)\pmod{101} = 84\pmod{101}  \implies x_1 = 4$

Our second result is

$$x \equiv x_0 + 5 x_1 \pmod {5^2} \equiv 24 \pmod {5^2}$$

Next, use the [*Chinese Remainder
Theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to
solve the simultaneous congruence's

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod {2^2} , ~~ x \equiv 24\pmod {5^2}$$

The result is

$$x \equiv 24 \pmod{2^2 \times 5^2}$$

Check the answer

$$2^{24} = 5 \pmod {101} ~~ \Large{\checkmark}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: Do you mean $29$ instead of $101$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: Which $101$ are you referring to? Looking at the problem, it looks totally different. Did an edit totally change the problem?